# Node crashing with typeinfo for boost:io:basic_altstringbuf error

Tags: rosnode, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In GDB, I see "SIGSEGV" signal received and then the following output

```
0x00000000004603e0 in typeinfo for boost::io::basic_altstringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > ()
```

A node handle is declared elsewhere and set via an accessor in the class where this crash is occuring.  The code leading up to the line where crash occurs is creating a publisher object using that node handle.  Once the publisher is created, a function is called and passed that publisher object by reference

Logging statements before the function call that is crashing show that the all the objects involved appear to be valid.

Any hints/ideas what this error means or how to debug this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203636/node-crashing-with-typeinfo-for-boost:io:basic_altstringbuf-error/) by [crazyorc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20596/crazyorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some deeper code inspection, the crash occurred in an instance of a class that was being accessed via an interface pointer which the class didn't inherit from.  All the required methods were implemented but none of them were declared virtual.

Modifying the class to inherit from the expected interface definition got rid of the crash.

---

Originally posted by [crazyorc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20596/crazyorc/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0